# Node-RED jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, node-red

I want to perform a GET request in Node-RED using jQuery:

```
$.get( "url", { data: "whatever"}).done(function( data){
     return data;
});
```

However it gives me the following error in the debugger:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I have installed jquery through npm.

How can I use jQuery (and other external libraries) inside Node-RED?

## --EDIT--

Thanks to the comments I learned jQuery is not needed and undesirable. Therefore, I am trying to use the build-in HTTP request node. However, I am having trouble with escaped characters. The request parameters should be of the following form:

```
localhost:port/path?tx="{{payload}}"
```

I can successfully get the string part in, however I can't get the enclosing quotation marks in, they keep getting transformed to HTML numbers in the request. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: if all you're trying to is make network requests, you shouldnt include a large library for functions that are natively available to you. https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the build in HTTP-request node?

Comment: @hardillb I need to add parameters to the GET request, is that possible using the request node?

Comment: Yes, the URL field can be passed in and out might even support mustash format (I'm on my phone so can't double check just now)

Comment: @hardillb I am having trouble with quotation marks being escaped (see my update), do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: This is now a totally different question, ask a new one

Answer (score 2):

Libraries can be loaded into the `functionGlobalContext` in the settings.js file which can be found in your Node-RED userDir. This directory is listed in the first few lines when Node-RED starts up but it is normally found in `~/.node-red`

A detailed description can be found in the Node-RED docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration)

But basically you follow this pattern:

```
...
functionGlobalContext: { osModule:require('os') },
...
```

Then in the function node use the following syntax to get a handle to the library:

```
var myos = global.get('osModule');
```

Having said that you really shouldn't be trying to use the jquery library in the function node, you gain very little that can't be done using the built in HTTP-request node or the native node.js http function.